# A property of product of sequence being small

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

Let $a \in (0,1)$ and a monotonically (strictly) decreasing sequence of non-negative numbers $t_n \to 0$ be given.

Define $$b_n = t_n(1+a) + a.$$

How can I show that for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $n_0$ such that $n \geq n_0$ implies $$b_1\times b_2 \times \cdots \times b_n \leq \epsilon?$$

Is it possible to quantify $n_0$ in terms of the $\epsilon$ and $a$?

To show this one could use the binomial theorem, but the cross terms are hard to make small.

Comment: Fix $a<b<1$ and $N_0$ so large that $t_{N_0}<(b-a)/2$, so $t_n(1+a)+a<b$ for all $n\geqslant N_0$. Then $b_1\ldots b_{N_0+n}\leqslant B b^n$, where $B=\prod_{i=1}^{N_0}b_i$. Since $B$ is fixed and $0<b<1$, $\lim_n b_n\to 0$.

Comment: A *sufficient condition* for $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_1\cdots b_n=0$ is $|b_n|<1-\delta$ for some *fixed* $\delta>0$ and suffficiently large $n$. Here $b_n$ is positive and therefore $|b_n|=b_n$. Can it be inferred that exists $N\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $\delta>0$ s.t. $b_n<1-\delta$ for all $n>N$ from $b_n = t_n(1+a) + a$?